# My PHP code is telling me that my username is undefined on line 12, but I though I had it defined

Tags: php, html

I am struggling to understand why my code is telling me that my username is undefined whenever I try to load up this page. the error is Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/jmask072/public_html/login.php on line 12. Any help is appreciated. How would I go about defining it if I didn't define it?

```
<?php
    $users = array("user" => '$2y$10$yHL4GKr4pKxnBJ1L2xlqYuI/k0kviae2NbIQNJLFeXgVclT2hZeDi');
        $isLoggedIn = false;
        $errors = array();
        $required = array("username", "pass");
        foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$value]) || empty($_POST[$value])) {
                $errors[] = "please fill out the form";
            }
        }
        
        if (array_key_exists($_POST['username'],$users)) {
            $userPassword = $_POST['pass'];
            $dbPass = $users[$_POST['username']];
            if (password_verify($userPassword,$dbPass) === true) {
                $isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                $isLoggedIn = false;
                $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
            }
                
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
        }

require_once("Template.php");

$page = new Template("My Login");
$page->addHeadElement("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\">");
$page->addHeadElement("<script src='hello.js'></script>");
$page->finalizeTopSection();
$page->finalizeBottomSection();

print $page->getTopSection();

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print "Error";
    }
}
else if ($isLoggedIn === true) {
    print "Hello, you are logged in";
}

    
    
print "<form action =\"login_action.php\" method =\"POST\" class=\"form-signin\">";
print "<h1>Please sign in</h1>\n";
print "<label for=\"inputUser\">Username</label>";
print "<input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" id=\"inputPassword\" placeholder=\"password\">";
print "<button type=\"submit\"> Sign in</button>";

print $page->getBottomSection();
?>
```

Comment: No where in your form do you post an input with the name `username`, so `$_POST['username']` will always be undefined. Another note, you could separate out your HTML to be outside of the PHP tags `<?php ?>` instead of printing them.

Comment: You don't, in fact, seem to have an input element with a name of "username". Is this the whole source document?

Comment: You will need to have an input with the name `username` for it to populate the `$_POST['username']` on the post request, you're also assuming the post values exist on the get request, you should check for either the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` before checking that the post values are set before accessing them.

Comment: This is the entire source, how would I go about implementing the input "username"? I thought I had it implemented near the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issues here is you're accessing the `$_POST` variables on a `GET` request, the values you're looking for won't be set since the form hasn't been filled out and sent to the server yet, you also don't have an input for the user to input their name yet you're trying to access it with `$_POST['username']`.

You'll have to check whether the request is a `POST` or a `GET` before you try to access variables - because they might not exist yet, and also add an input for the username to it's accessible when posted.

```
<?php

$errors = array();
$isLoggedIn = false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $users = array("user" => '$2y$10$yHL4GKr4pKxnBJ1L2xlqYuI/k0kviae2NbIQNJLFeXgVclT2hZeDi');
    $required = array("username", "pass");

    foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$value]) || empty($_POST[$value])) {
            $errors[] = "please fill out the form";
        }
    }

    if (array_key_exists($_POST['username'], $users)) {
        $userPassword = $_POST['pass'];
        $dbPass = $users[$_POST['username']];

        if (password_verify($userPassword, $dbPass)) {
            $isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
            $isLoggedIn = false;
            $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
    }
}

require_once("Template.php");

$page = new Template("My Login");
$page->addHeadElement("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\">");
$page->addHeadElement("<script src='hello.js'></script>");
$page->finalizeTopSection();
$page->finalizeBottomSection();

print $page->getTopSection();

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print "$error<br/>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else if ($isLoggedIn === true) {
    print "Hello, you are logged in";
}

?>

<form action="login_action.php" method="POST" class="form-signin">
    <h1>Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputUser">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="inputUser">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="inputPassword">
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>

<?php print $page->getBottomSection(); ?>
```

The `name` attribute on inputs is the key that will later be used as the key for accessing the given value on the `$_POST` array. This `$_POST` variable array is also only populated in a `POST` request as stated in the documentation.

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.¹

- [PHP Manual: Predefined Variables: $_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post) ¹